# Equation of the tangents

Tags: calculus, polynomials

> What is the equation of the tangent to $y=x^3-6x^2+12x+2$ that is parallel to the line $y=3x$ ?

I have no idea, how to solve, no example is given in the book! 
Appreciate your help!

Comment: Where did all the comments go?

Comment: Calculus sure does help a lot here. The calculus-free approach is a little bit involved...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:  what is the slope of $y=3x$?  Then what is the slope of $y=x^3-6x^2+12x+2$    (which depends upon $x$)?  You need to find an $x$ where the slopes match.  Then find a $y$ so that $(x,y)$ is a point on the cubic.  Now you have  a point and a slope, giving you the equation for the line.

Added:  the slope of the tangent is $y'=3x^2-12x+12\ \ $  ,  which we are told is $3\ \ $.  Solving $3=3x^2-12x+12\ \ $  gives $x=1 \text{ or } 3\ \ $  .  So the  points of tangency are $(1,9)$ and $(3,11)\ \ $.  The lines with slope $3$ that pass through these points are $y=3x+6\ $ and $y=3x+2\ \ $.   A figure is at [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%7By=x%5E3-6x%5E2%2b12x%2b2,y=3x%2b6,y=3x%2b2%7D)

Comment: there is no given (x,y) so how can i do?

Comment: Can you take the derivative of your cubic?  That is the slope of the tangent line at each point.  You want a slope of 3-that is the point of being parallel to y=3x.  So set the derivative to 3 and solve the equation for x.

Comment: aww..ok. so it is like this
y=3x^3-1-12x^2-1+12x+2 ? thx

Comment: No-I'll add to the above.

Comment: @Thijs:  good catch.  I had missed the $-1$s, which is why I added the detailed solution, but it appears OP did take the derivative correctly.

Comment: @Ross: When presenting hints and/or solutions to problems like the present problem, I've found it helpful to notationally distinguish between the coordinates of the tangency point and the $x$, $y$ variables used in the functions, by letting $(a,b)$ be the coordinates of the tangency point. I don't have time now to write a detailed solution using this approach (and I probably shouldn't, but rather encourage Sb Sangpi to do this), but here's an example I wrote 7 months ago in another group: http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=7363805

Comment: @Dave L. Renfro:  Good point.  I've seen the problem and will try to remember to do that.

Comment: @Ross: One of the reasons I started doing things this way (many years ago) was to lessen the number of times I'd see something like $y = (1 + xe^x)x$ for the tangent line to $y = xe^x$ at $(0,0)$ on homework, quizzes, and tests! Using $(a,b)$ or $(a,f(a))$ didn't completely eliminate nonlinear "tangent lines" given by students, but it definitely helped.

Comment: great! I like it! Thx alot Ross. I'm very happy! God bless you all! ;)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The equation of the tangent to the graph of $f(x)$ at $(a,f(a))$ is given by

$$y=f(a)+f^{\prime }(a)(x-a)=f^{\prime }(a)x+f(a)-f^{\prime }(a)a.\tag{1}$$

Two lines with equations $y=mx+b$ and $y=m^{\prime }x+b^{\prime }$ are
parallel if and only if $m=m^{\prime }$. Hence, the family of lines parallel
to the line $y=3x$ is given by $y=3x+b$. So, we must have

$$f^{\prime }(a)x+f(a)-f^{\prime }(a)a=3x+b.\tag{2}$$

Equating coefficients we get $f^{\prime }(a)=3$ and $f(a)-f^{\prime }(a)a=b$. Since the derivative of $f(x)=x^{3}-6x^{2}+12x+2$ at $x=a$ is $f^{\prime
}(a)=3a^{2}-12a+12$, we obtain the system of two equations

$$3a^{2}-12a+12=3,\tag{3}$$

$$a^{3}-6a^{2}+12a+2-3a=b,$$

which is equivalent to

$$a=1,b=6\tag{4}$$

or

$$a=3,b=2.\tag{5}$$

Hence the equations of the two tangent lines are

$$y=3x+6\tag{6}$$

and

$$y=3x+2.\tag{7}$$

Comment: step by step great help! looking forward more help! thx alot Tavares. God bless you! ;)

Comment: @Sb Sangpi: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Look at a taylor series (ref [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series), [2](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TaylorSeries.html)) of your function about a point $x_c$ of order 1 (linear).

Then find which $x_c$ produces a line parallel to $3x$, or has a slope of $3$. 
*Hint!* There are two solutions actually.

Comment: Do you reckon that someone who asks this kind of question is up for Taylor series?

Comment: @gerry - yes I do. Derivatives of polynomials are trivial and the rest is algebra. Maybe this is an opportunity to learn something.

Comment: I have 80 students this semester who think derivatives of polynomials are anything but trivial, and that algebra is not far removed from Sanskrit.

Comment: @gerry - rofl - On the other hand, somebody motivated enough to post on MathSE is already above the average student. BTW, do you grade on a curve?

Comment: Yes - but I'm not saying *which* curve.